# Unable to script installation of NuGet Package Provider in Powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am trying to install the NuGet Package Provider using this command.

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

I've also tried adding the `-Confirm:$false` flag. I continue to be prompted for confirmation.

For example,

```
NuGet provider is required to continue
PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to 
interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet
provider must be available in 'C:\Program 
Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
'C:\Users\Booker\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You 
can also install the NuGet provider by
running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -
Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install
and import the NuGet provider now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

I want to complete this installation in a script. How can I bypass the confirmation prompt?

Comment: Do you mean that even after using `Install-PackageProvider NuGet ...` you are not able to see the package provider? 
Have you tried adding a
 `Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable -Verbose` to see if it shows the provider.

Comment: No I mean that there is no way to run the command Install-PackageProvider without interaction if you are on a system that doesn't have nuget cli tools. The workaround I've found is to download nuget.exe from somewhere and put it on my path before attempting to add package providers. When I do that then the rest of the script is able to run without interaction. It just seems odd to me that this cmdlet doesn't have any way to bypass the confirmation prompt if your system is missing the nuget cli tools.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? I can't reproduce the behavior you've described. $PSVersionTable reports => PSVersion: 5.0.10586.117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works to get the Nuget Package Provider installed without confirmation.

```
Find-PackageProvider -Name 'Nuget' -ForceBootstrap -IncludeDependencies
```